# How to interact with Electron radio buttons on the tray menu?

Tags: electron

I'm using Electron and I'm creating a tray icon for my application. Electron's own documentation (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/tray#tray-popupcontextmenu-position-os-x-windows) shows that I can have selectable radiobuttons on the menu with the following code:

```
  const {app, Menu, Tray} = require('electron')

  let tray = null
  app.on('ready', () => {
    tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')
    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      {label: 'Item1', type: 'radio'},
      {label: 'Item2', type: 'radio'},
      {label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true},
      {label: 'Item4', type: 'radio'}
    ])
    tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
  })
```

This creates the buttons, but I couldn't find anywhere on the documentation how to get events and read data from these buttons. How?

Comment: Did the below answer your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you [`Menu.buildFromTemplate`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menubuildfromtemplatetemplate) you actually define [`MenuItem`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item) objects.

Those have click callback with signature `click(menuItem, browserWindow, event)` let you access practically anything from the containing BrowserWindow

For example

```
  const handleClick = (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    // ...
  }
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {label: 'Item1', type: 'radio', click: handleClick},
    {label: 'Item2', type: 'radio', click: handleClick},
    {label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', click: handleClick, checked: true},
    {label: 'Item4', type: 'radio', click: handleClick}
  ])
```